# Is it better to remove software using Ubuntu Sofware Center or Synaptic Package Manager?

Tags: software-center, uninstall, synaptic

I'm very new and I accidentally installed 6 text editors via the Synaptic Package Manager, and one from the Ubuntu Software Center. I know I can "remove" the text editing software with one click in the Ubuntu Software Center. Is that the best way to remove them or would it be better to remove them via the Synaptic Package Mangager or perhaps there's an even better way?

Comment: I have always used Ubuntu software center for all requirements of installation and un-installation and it is pretty cool and easy to use and so I feel, for a beginner, it is the simplest and easiest way

Answer (score 1):

They both do the same when you remove a package, so they're equally good and it's all up to you which one you prefer. Synaptic provides advanced functionality, but you don't need that for simply uninstalling software.

Comment: Thanks very much. I used the Software Center and it worked fine.